# How to use CCBReader in cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3 for an Android Project?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I am curious to start working on Cocos2D-X platform. However, I am not able to figure out how to use CCBReader in cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3. Any idea?

I tried using

```
using namespace cocos2d::extension;
```

or

```
USING_NS_CC_EXT;
```

But it is giving compilation error

**error: 'USING_NS_CC_EXT' does not name a type**

**error: 'extension' is not a namespace-name**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
CodeSnooker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

`using namespace extension;`

Hope it will be helpful :)